# Which font is used in G+ social?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

Any ideas which font is being used for Google Plus social "g"?

[image: http://socialsolutionscollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/google-Plus-icon.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure it started out as Gentium. It's open source and on Google Fonts, iirc.

Comment: Wrong answer. This is Catull BQ.

Comment: Right you are. That's what I get for answering from memory ;)

Answer (score 11):

Actually, this is [Catull Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/search/catull/fonts/) with minor manual changes. It was created in 1982 by German designer Gustav Jaeger for Berthold. Also see [this](http://www.google.ru/search?q=Catull%20typeface&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=2GB_UYfrM4fX4ATM2gE&ved=0CEwQsAQ&biw=1573&bih=987).

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is custom... Therefore, do not find 100% similars the font.

Answer (score -3):

The font family is Catull BQ Regular. Take a look at the 24-bit bitmap image below:
[image: Google+]

Comment: Already answered.

Comment: @Lucian, sorry, but I make my own rules at Stack Exchange.